# Adding new node cassandra 3.x

Tags: cassandra

We are in the process of adding new nodes to our existing cassandra 3.x cluster. Basically following the steps outlined in this article (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html).

Currently, out 3.x cluster does incremental repairs. What I'm not 100 percent sure about is if we need to do anything after we do the node cleanup. Specifically, are our new added nodes setup to do incremental repairs after following the procedure listed above?

Thanks
Marshall

Answer (score 0):

Adding a node involves **rebalancing the token distribution** among nodes in the cluster and **bootstrapping** the new node. Repair is a regular maintenance process and it's not necessarily needed in the adding node process.

For the token **redistribution** part, simplified example is if your have 20 tokens and 4 nodes initially. If random enough, each node would be the primary node for 5 tokens. When add a node and change the configuration, 20 tokens would be distributed to 5 nodes and each node would be the primary node for 4 tokens. When you run **bootstrap** to add the new node, the new node knows what tokens belongs to it and it will **stream** missing tokens from other existing nodes. After bootstrapping is done, nodetool **cleanup** on the existing nodes would remove tokens which don't belong to them anymore. To sum up, **bootstrapping** new node would **redistribute** tokens and **stream** objects to new nodes based on the distribution. you don't need **repair** in this process to stream data. **cleanup** would remove objects which the ownership is changed.

However, repair is a regular process to guarantee data consistency and incremental or full options are out of scope in terms of talking about adding node.

Good reference to read under the hood on what happens when you c[hange the topology of a cluster](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/topo_changes.html)